# Change a declared data type of a variable inside a function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script where I want to declare a variable data type at the beginning, and there is a function that changes this data type on certain conditions. I can make it work if this is done outside of the function, but I can't change the data type inside the function, even though I use scope modifiers.

If I put this in script foobar:

```
[string]$foo = "123"
[int]$foo = $foo
$foo.GetType()
```

And execute the script:

```
PS C:\> .\foobar.ps1

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

But if I put this:

```
[string]$foo = "123"
Function bar {
    [int]$script:foo = $foo
    $foo.GetType()
}
bar
```

And I execute:

```
PS C:\> .\bar.ps1

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

The important note here is that the second scenario only happens if you execute the code from a script. The result will be different when executing directly from terminal.
I want the data type to change to integer on both scenarios. Any ideas?

Comment: Change `$foo.GetType()` to `$script:foo.GetType()`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Nicely spotted. This should be an actual answer.

Comment: I still get the same result. Data type is still string.
So far, the workaround that I found was to not declare the data type at the beginning, and define an alternative variable for the sting data type. But this is not ideal.

Comment: @AmirSalehAlavi are you hoping to persist the change in data type in the variable in the parent scope? It can certainly be done, but it's a bit of an antipattern. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Pass in reference variables like below

```
[string]$foo = "123"

Function bar([ref]$foo) {
[int]($foo)  ='123'
    
 ##  Get-Variable -Name foo -Scope global | select fullname
$foo.GetType()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what that output object would be with `[OutputType()]`

```
[string]$foo = "123"
Function bar {
    [OutputType([int])]
    [int]$script:foo = $foo
    $foo.GetType()
}
bar
```

You can read more about it here [outputType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_outputtypeattribute?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Is it the complete code? I still get the same result.
I read about OutputType, but I couldn't find a solution to the problem.